# Bundling server side code with webpack 2

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to bundle server side code with `target: node` but the code isn't transpiled (I see the source code in the build file) and there is the entry file only without any imported modules in it.

```
// webpack.config.server.dev.babel.js
import path from 'path'
const SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, '../server')
const BUILD = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/')

const babelConfig = {
  babelrc: false,
  presets: [['env', {
    targets: { node: 'current' },
    modules: false,
    //useBuiltIns: true
  }], 'react']
}

export default {
  context: SRC,
  entry: './',
  output: {
    path: BUILD,
    filename: 'server.bundle.js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    noParse: /node_modules/,
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: babelConfig
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader/locals',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[folder]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
            camelCase: true
          }
        }
      ] 
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  performance: { hints: false },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'shared'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config.module.noParse = true` caused the behavior.